# Validate authentication cookie with ASP.NET Core 2.1 / 3+ Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cookies, asp.net-core-3.1, asp.net-core-identity

When using Cookie Authentication in ASP.NET Core 2 (with or without `Identity`) it might happen, that a user's email or name is changed, or even the account is deleted during the cookie's lifetime. That's why the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x) point out, that the cookie should be validated. The example in the docs is commented with

> The approach described here is triggered on every request. This can
>   result in a large performance penalty for the app.

So I am wondering **what is the best pattern to validate the cookie principal**. What I did in `Startup.cs` is to subscribe to the `OnValidatePrincipal` event and check the pricipal's validity e.g. every 5 minutes by appending a `LastValidatedOn` claim to the cookie like so:

```cs
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    // other cookie options go here

    options.Events.OnValidatePrincipal = async context =>
    {
        const string claimType = "LastValidatedOn";
        const int reValidateAfterMinutes = 5;

        if (!(context.Principal?.Identity is ClaimsIdentity claimIdentity)) return;

        if (!context.Principal.HasClaim(c => c.Type == claimType) ||
            DateTimeOffset.Now.UtcDateTime.Subtract(new DateTime(long.Parse(context.Principal.Claims.First(c => c.Type == claimType).Value))) > TimeSpan.FromMinutes(reValidateAfterMinutes))
        {
            var mgr = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<SignInManager<ApplicationUser>>();
            var user = await mgr.UserManager.FindByNameAsync(claimIdentity.Name);
            if (user != null && claimIdentity.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "AspNet.Identity.SecurityStamp")?.Value == await mgr.UserManager.GetSecurityStampAsync(user))
            {
                claimIdentity.FindAll(claimType).ToList().ForEach(c => claimIdentity.TryRemoveClaim(c));
                claimIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(claimType, DateTimeOffset.Now.UtcDateTime.Ticks.ToString(), typeof(long).ToString()));
                context.ShouldRenew = true;
            }
            else
            {
                context.RejectPrincipal();
                await mgr.SignOutAsync();
            }
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Identity uses a security stamp which is a GUID stored in the database against the user. It's updated whenever the account changes and it's periodically compared against the existing security stamp stored in the cookie (which is invalidated when different).

Comment: @MarkG How can we influence how often this comparison with the persistent store takes place. With every request, once a day, ...? It's a about the possible performance penalty [mentioned in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x).

Comment: Identity uses the [ValidationInterval](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.securitystampvalidatoroptions.validationinterval) property which defaults to 30 mins.

Answer (score 27):

@MarkG pointed me into the right direction, thanks. After having a closer look at [the source code](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetIdentity/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin/SecurityStampValidator.cs) for `SecurityStampValidator` and `Identity` things became clear to me. Actually, the sample code I posted with my question is unnecessary, because ASP.NET Core Identity brings the feature in a better fashion out-of-the-box.

As I didn't find a summary like this yet, maybe it will be helpful to others, too.

### What has nothing to do with authentication cookie validation

... but still good to know...

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.Cookie.Expiration = TimeSpan.FromDays(30);
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(30);
    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
});
```

**ExpireTimeSpan**

Defaults to `TimeSpan.FromDays(14)`

The issue time of the authentication ticket is part of the cookie (`CookieValidatePrincipalContext.Properties.IssuedUtc`). When the cookie is sent back to the server, the current time minus the issue time must be **greater** than `ExpireTimeSpan`. If it is not, the user will be signed out without further investigation. In practice, setting the `ExpireTimeSpan`, mostly goes together with `SlidingExpiration` set to `true`. This is a means to ensure that the user is actively working with the app, and did not e.g. leave the device back unattended. Negative `TimeSpan`s will sign the user off immediately (but not `TimeSpan.Zero`).

### What is needed to control authentication cookie validation

```
services.AddOptions();
services.Configure<SecurityStampValidatorOptions>(options =>
{
    // This is the key to control how often validation takes place
    options.ValidationInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
});
```

#### ValidationInterval

Defaults to `TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30)`

This determines the time span after which the validity of the authentication cookie will be checked against persistent storage. It is accomplished by calling the `SecurityStampValidator` for **every request** to the server. If the current time minus the cookie's issue time is **less or equal to** `ValidationInterval`, a call to `ValidateSecurityStampAsync` will occur. This means
`ValidationInterval = TimeSpan.Zero` leads to calling the `ValidateSecurityStampAsync` for each request.

**Note** `UserManager` must support getting security stamps or it will fail. For a custom user manager or user store, both must properly implement `IUserSecurityStampStore<TUser>`.

#### Sequence of loading services in `Startup`

The thing to be aware of is: `services. AddIdentity()` also sets defaults for the authentication cookie. If you add it after `services.ConfigureApplicationCookie()` this will override the previous settings. 
I called `services.Configure<SecurityStampValidatorOptions>()` after the previous ones above.

Thanks again to @MarkG for showing the way.