# Erratic Signing Out with IdentityServer 4

Tags: identityserver4, oidc-client-js

We have users complaining because they are redirected to the login page of the Identity Server while in the middle of their work (and thus losing their current work). We have endeavoured to configure a sliding expiration, so I'm not sure why this is happening.

I realise there is quite a bit of code in this post. But there are a lot of moving parts and I want to give as much information as possible.

This behavour is arratic and it is hard to report an exact reproducable event. In my testing, I've been ejected at random times and it is hard to understand whether it has any relationship to any of the cofigurations which I have set. In my mind, I should not be ejected at all, as a silent sign-in is always sent during the `addAccessTokenExpiring` event.

The setup that we have is:

- an Idp (using IdentityServer 4)
- A client app, implemented using Vue.js (using Typescript)
- An API, written in ASP.NET Core 5

The config and auth service which we have written are:
**auth.config.ts**

```
import { Log, UserManagerSettings, WebStorageStateStore } from "oidc-client";
import AppConfig from "./invariable/app.config";
/* eslint-disable */
class AuthConfig {
    public settings: UserManagerSettings;
    private baseUrl: string;

    constructor() {
        this.baseUrl = AppConfig.RunTimeConfig.VUE_APP_APPURL || process.env.VUE_APP_APPURL;

        this.settings = {
            userStore: new WebStorageStateStore({ store: window.localStorage }),
            authority: AppConfig.RunTimeConfig.VUE_APP_IDPURL || process.env.VUE_APP_IDPURL,
            client_id: AppConfig.RunTimeConfig.VUE_APP_CLIENTID || process.env.VUE_APP_CLIENTID,
            client_secret: AppConfig.RunTimeConfig.VUE_APP_CLIENTSECRET || process.env.VUE_APP_CLIENTSECRET,
            redirect_uri: this.baseUrl + process.env.VUE_APP_AUTHCALLBACK,
            automaticSilentRenew: false,
            silent_redirect_uri: this.baseUrl + process.env.VUE_APP_SILENTREFRESH,
            response_type: "code",
            response_mode: "query",
            scope: "our_scopes",
            post_logout_redirect_uri: this.baseUrl + process.env.VUE_APP_SIGNOUT_CALLBACK,
            filterProtocolClaims: true,
            loadUserInfo: true,
            revokeAccessTokenOnSignout: true,
            staleStateAge: 300, // should match access_token lifetime.
        };
    }
}
/* eslint-enable */

const authConfig = new AuthConfig();

export default authConfig;
```

**auth.service.ts**

```
import { UserManagerSettings, User, UserManager } from "oidc-client";
import authConfig from "@/config/auth.config";
import axios, { AxiosResponse } from "axios";
import { Ajax } from "@/config/invariable/ajax";
import AccessClaim from "@/domain/general/accessclaim";
import _ from "lodash";
import store from "@/store";
import StoreNamespaces from "@/config/invariable/store.namespaces";
import Token from "@/store/token/token";

export class AuthService {
    private userManager: UserManager;
    private tokenStore: string;

    constructor(private settings: UserManagerSettings) {
        this.settings = settings;
        this.userManager = new UserManager(this.settings);
        this.tokenStore = StoreNamespaces.tokenModule;
    }

    public addEvents(): void {
        this.userManager.events.addUserSignedOut(() => {
            this.signInAgain();
        });

        this.userManager.events.addAccessTokenExpired(() => {
            console.log("Token expired");
            this.clearLocalState();
            console.log("Stale state cleaned up");
        });

        this.userManager.events.addAccessTokenExpiring(() => {
            console.log("Access token about to expire.");
            this.signInAgain();
        });

        this.userManager.events.addSilentRenewError(() => {
            // custom logic here
            console.log("An error happened whilst silently renewing the token.");
        });
    }

    public clearLocalState(): Promise<void> {
        return this.userManager.clearStaleState();
    }

    public getUserOnLoad(): Promise<User> {

        return this.userManager.getUser().then((user) => {
            if (!_.isNil(user) && !user.expired) {

                console.log("first load sign-in");
                const decodedIdToken = user.profile;

                if (!_.isNil(decodedIdToken.store) && !_.isArray(decodedIdToken.store)) decodedIdToken.store = [decodedIdToken.store];
                if (!_.isNil(decodedIdToken.classification) && !_.isArray(decodedIdToken.classification)) decodedIdToken.classification = [decodedIdToken.classification];
                if (!_.isNil(decodedIdToken.location) && !_.isArray(decodedIdToken.location)) decodedIdToken.location = [decodedIdToken.location];
                if (!_.isArray(decodedIdToken.app)) decodedIdToken.app = [decodedIdToken.app];

                const token = new Token();
                token.accessToken = user.access_token;
                token.idToken = user.id_token;
                token.storeClaims = decodedIdToken.store || [];
                token.userType = decodedIdToken.usertype;
                token.isLoggedIn = user && !user.expired;
                token.app = decodedIdToken.app;
                token.userName = decodedIdToken.name ?? "Unknown User";

                store.dispatch(`${this.tokenStore}/setToken`, token);

                return user;
            } else {
                return this.signInAgain();
            }
        });
    }

    public async getUserIfLoggedIn(): Promise<User | null> {
        const currentUser: User | null = await this.userManager.getUser();
        const loggedIn = currentUser !== null && !currentUser.expired;

        return loggedIn ? currentUser : null;
    }

    public async isLoggedIn(): Promise<boolean> {
        const currentUser: User | null = await this.userManager.getUser();

        return currentUser !== null && !currentUser.expired;
    }

    public login(): Promise<void> {
        return this.userManager.signinRedirect();
    }

    public logout(): Promise<void> {
        return this.userManager.signoutRedirect();
    }

    public getAccessToken(): Promise<string> {
        return this.userManager.getUser().then((data: any) => {
            return data.access_token;
        });
    }

    public signInAgain(): Promise<User> {

        return this.userManager
            .signinSilent()
            .then((user) => {

                console.log("silent sign-in");
                const decodedIdToken = user.profile;

                if (!_.isNil(decodedIdToken.store) && !_.isArray(decodedIdToken.store)) decodedIdToken.store = [decodedIdToken.store];
                if (!_.isNil(decodedIdToken.classification) && !_.isArray(decodedIdToken.classification)) decodedIdToken.classification = [decodedIdToken.classification];
                if (!_.isNil(decodedIdToken.location) && !_.isArray(decodedIdToken.location)) decodedIdToken.location = [decodedIdToken.location];
                if (!_.isArray(decodedIdToken.app)) decodedIdToken.app = [decodedIdToken.app];

                const token = new Token();
                token.accessToken = user.access_token;
                token.idToken = user.id_token;
                token.storeClaims = decodedIdToken.store || [];
                token.userType = decodedIdToken.usertype;
                token.isLoggedIn = user && !user.expired;
                token.app = decodedIdToken.app;
                token.userName = decodedIdToken.name ?? "Unknown User";

                store.dispatch(`${this.tokenStore}/setToken`, token);

                return user;
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log("silent error");
                console.log(err);

                this.login();
                return err;
            });
    }

    public getAccessClaims(userDetails: any): Promise<AxiosResponse<any>> {
        return axios.post(`${Ajax.appApiBase}/PermittedUse/GetAccessesForUser`, userDetails).then((resp: AxiosResponse<any>) => {
            return resp.data;
        });
    }

    public getPermissions(userDetails: any, siteId: number | null): Promise<AxiosResponse<any>> {
        return axios.get(`${Ajax.appApiBase}/PermittedUse/GetPermissions/${siteId ?? 0}`).then((resp: AxiosResponse<any>) => {
            return resp.data;
        });
    }

    public constructAccess(userType: string, claims: Array<AccessClaim>): Array<AccessClaim> {
        switch (userType) {
            case "storeadmin":
            case "storeuser":
                return _.filter(claims, (claim) => {
                    return claim.claim === "store";
                });
            case "warduser":
                return _.filter(claims, (claim) => {
                    return claim.claim === "classification";
                });
        }

        return Array<AccessClaim>();
    }

    public getBookableLocations(userType: string, claims: Array<AccessClaim>): Array<AccessClaim> {
        switch (userType) {
            case "storeadmin":
            case "storeuser":
                return _.filter(claims, (claim) => {
                    return claim.claim === "store";
                });
            case "warduser":
                return _.filter(claims, (claim) => {
                    return claim.claim === "location";
                });
        }

        return Array<AccessClaim>();
    }
}

export const authService = new AuthService(authConfig.settings);
```

On the Idp, our client configuration is:

```
ClientName = IcClients.Names.ConsumablesApp,
ClientId = IcClients.ConsumablesApp,

RequireConsent = false,
AccessTokenLifetime = TokenConfig.AccessTokenLifetime, // 300 for test purposes
IdentityTokenLifetime = TokenConfig.IdentityTokenLifetime, // 300
AllowOfflineAccess = true,
RefreshTokenUsage = TokenUsage.ReUse,
RefreshTokenExpiration = TokenExpiration.Sliding,
UpdateAccessTokenClaimsOnRefresh = true,
RequireClientSecret = true,
AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,
RequirePkce = true,

AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,
AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken = true,
RedirectUris = new List<string>
{
    "https://localhost:44336/authcallback.html",
    "https://localhost:8090/authcallback.html",
    "https://localhost:44336/silent-refresh.html",
    "https://localhost:8090/silent-refresh.html"
},
PostLogoutRedirectUris = new List<string>
{
    "https://localhost:44336/signout-callback-oidc.html",
    "https://localhost:8090/signout-callback-oidc.html"
},
AllowedScopes = new List<string>
{
    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
    IdentityServerConstants.LocalApi.ScopeName,
    IcAccessScopes.IcAccessClaimsScope,
    IdentityResources.UserDetails,
    IcAccessScopes.ConsumablesScope
},
ClientSecrets = { new Secret("oursecret".Sha256())}
```

At the Idp, we are using ASP.NET Core Identity:

```
services.AddIdentity<IdpUser, IdentityRole<int>>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<IdpDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = cookieDuration; // set to 1 hour
    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
});
```

My expectation is that the sliding window should be extended every 5 minutes, as the user should be signed in again silently before the token expires.

When monitoring the IDP in my dev environment, one thing which I did note is that the `checksession` call is only being made once, when the user logs in. The wiki says that the `checksession` call should happen every 2s (by default). I have not changed this default (not knowingly). I even expressly set the `checkSessionInterval` property to 2000 to ensure that it was set to 2s.

The other thing I want to set out is the silent refresh html file, as I realise the CSP stuff can play into this:

```
<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="frame-src 'self' <%= VUE_APP_IDPURL %>; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';" />
</head>
<body>
  <script src="./oidc-client.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    (function refresh() {
      window.location.hash = decodeURIComponent(window.location.hash);
      new Oidc.UserManager({
        // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/camelcase
        response_mode: "query",
        userStore: new Oidc.WebStorageStateStore({
          store: window.localStorage,
        }),
      })
        .signinSilentCallback()
        .then(function() {
          console.log("****************************************signinSilentCallback****************************************");
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
          debug;
          console.log(err);
        });
    })();
  </script>
</body>
```

If anyone can shed any light on this, it would be much appreciated.

Some further information. As a test, I set the refrsh time for the token and the cookie lifetime for the identity cookie to both be 10 hours (36,000s).

I am still getting reports of Users being kicked out after 45 minutes.

Comment: you are not signed out due to redeployment of IdentityServer or the client?

Comment: @ToreNestenius No. This happens in the ordinary course of usage. It is not due to a deployment of either client nor IDP.

Comment: I just had a thought. Should I be calling `ConfigureApplicationCookie` after I call `AddIdentityServer` (which, in turn, calls `AddAspNetIdentity`). Perhaps that last call is overriding my custom cookie settings. Although I note that `AddAspNetIdentity`  is not overriding the name of the cookie, when I give it a different name. in `ConfigureApplicationCookie`.

Comment: It is always a mess when you involve many different services that all wants to own the cookies. Ideally I would place ASP.NET identity in its own service.

Comment: IdentityServer is not a user store. It interfaces with user stores and does the job of implementing OAuth2/OpenIdConnect for those user stores. ASP.NET identity is one such user store. I need IdentityServer for the OAuth stuff.

Comment: in one of my applications I tied IdentityServer to the database of ASP.NET Identity, but I hosted/added the actual ASP.NET Identity user management service in a different application (for managing the users).

Comment: I'm not sure how the oidc-client checksession stuff would work in that setup. Sounds like you would have had to have hacked the `oidc-client` library (if you were using it). I seem to be having success by changing the `ValidationInterval` of the `SecurityStamp`. I think this has made the difference. This helped - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51468506/validate-authentication-cookie-with-asp-net-core-2-1-3-identity

Comment: New theory. Also related to the `SecurityStamp`. Quite often, our team (incl testers) are logged in using the same user. Sometimes, an update would be made to a User which would change the `SecurityStamp`. With each such change, I surmise that the cookie was revoked. So, changing the `ValidationInterval`  is really a bandaid over the real problem i.e. a `SecurityStamp` which is changing. I will test this over the weekend.

Comment: i would try to see what the logs in both ASP.NET Core and IdentityServer says (don't forget to set the logging level to Debug...)

Comment: Still struggling with this. The bugs are hard to read. It seems to say I'm authenticated and then not authenticated about 20 times every time I log in.
The SecurityStamp is weird. I set that to 5s using `services.Configure<SecurityStampValidatorOptions>(o => o.ValidationInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(SecurityTimestampDuration));` Now, when I log in, 5s later, I get logged out. So, the default for that setting is 30min, which explains why users were getting booted after about half and hour. But why? Validating the security stamp should not affect it if nothing changed on that user row.

Comment: Sorry, I have little experience using ASP.NET Identity, I try to avoid it as much as possible. but as your client is in JavaScript, I think the problem might be there? I mean the issue is how to determine where the source problem is? are your client "session" expired? is the problem that the API complains that the access token is expired?  Personally I would never put the "openid connect" client in JavaScript, better to do this in he backend, as most recommends now days.

Comment: Well, for posterity, I can explain why I was being logged out straight away. I made a mistake when logging in the user. I was using the IdentityServer4 extensions `HttpContext.SignInAsync(user, authProperties)`. In their own quickstart, they use the SignInManager to sign in and issue the cookie  `_signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(idpUser, model.Password, model.RememberLogin, true) == SignInResult.Success)`. The reason is, the SignInManager includes the SecurityTimestamp in the cookie. The IdentityServer4 extensions does not (because it is not for ASP.NET Identity).

Answer (score 1):

There's 2 conclusions I came to in resolving this and I would hesitate to say that it is a proper resolution to our problem.

1. There was a mistake in my Login code. I was using the IdentityServer4 extensions `HttpContext.SignInAsync(user, authProperties)` to create the session cookie. This is not the way to do things, if using ASP.NET Identity. For 1 reason, it does not include the SecurityStamp claim in the cookie. In their own quickstart, they use the `SignInManager` to sign in and issue the cookie `_signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(idpUser, model.Password, model.RememberLogin, true)`.
2. I needed to turn off the `SecurityStamp` validation feature in ASP.NET Identity. We had adjudged that we can live without it. You would think there would be a config setting for this, but I was not able to find it. So, at this stage, I have subclassed the `UserManager` and overridden the `SupportsUserSecurityStamp` property as follows: `public override bool SupportsUserSecurityStamp => false;`. Theoretically, this feature will now be turned off. Happy to be corrected if that is not the case or if there is a better way of doing it. (Would love to hear from a member of the ASP.NET team on this).

That's it.